# Vapor How to find user by email

Tags: swift, vapor

How to properly find user by email in vapor in login method and return that user or return error, 
I've tried:

```
    func login(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<User> {
    return try req.content.decode(User.self).map { loginUser in
        let query = User.query(on: req)
        return query
            .filter(\.email == loginUser.email)
            .first()
            .flatMap { user in
                return user!.save(on: req)
            }

        }
}
```

but I'm getting

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture' to return type 'User'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```swift
func login(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<User> {
    return try req.content.decode(User.self).flatMap { loginUser in
        return User.query(on: req)
            .filter(\.email == loginUser.email)
            .first()
            .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound, reason: "User not found"))
    }
}
```